# Message: Set sys_temp_dir in your php.ini after installed composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I've tried to install composer for my CodeIgniter project.

The installation was successful. But, when I type on command-line `composer --version`, it shows:

```
PHP temp directory (C:\Users\petik\AppData\Local\Temp) does not exist or is not writable to Composer. Set sys_temp_dir in your php.ini
Composer version 1.4.2 2017-05-17 08:17:52
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change TEMP folder in php.ini. look for entry `sys_temp_dir` in your php.ini file and change the tmp location and set correct permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I have same error on an debian where /tmp partition was full. Purge `rm -rf /tmp/*`, and message gone. May this help.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you use Windows you have to run your command line like an administrator 
**"Run as administrator"**

Answer (score 0):

For this error, If you don't have permission to edit php.ini file. My temporary solution is:

```
php -d open_base_dir="." -d sys_temp_dir="." /usr/local/bin/composer -v
```

You can run all your composer commands like this:

```
php -d open_base_dir="." -d sys_temp_dir="." /usr/local/bin/composer install
php -d open_base_dir="." -d sys_temp_dir="." /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

You can also use this command in other operations e.g.:
In magento2 for phpcbf:

```
php -d open_base_dir="." -d sys_temp_dir="."  vendor/bin/phpcbf --standard=Magento2 magento2/app/code/example/StockReserve --report-file="StockReserveAutoFixed.txt"
```

php -d sets variable in command line.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got the solution by doing the following steps:

1. Search **view advance system settings** then go to **environment variables** then in user variables edit TEMP and TMP both. And change them to **C:\Users\Bappy\AppData\Local\Temp** (here Bappy is User name)
2. Then go to `xampp>php>php.ini` and find `sys_temp_dir` and set `sys_temp_dir = "/temp"`