# php artisan serve gives 'Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: No such file or directory'

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

When I run the below command as the user I get fatal error in almalinux 8. I just installed a simple laravel project from the internet with simple commands in the user's home directory.

```
bash-4.4$ php artisan serve

   WARN  Mon Jul 17 01:26:11 2023 (115): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: No such file or directory (2).  

   WARN  Mon Jul 17 01:26:12 2023 (116): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: No such file or directory (2).  

   WARN  Mon Jul 17 01:26:12 2023 (117): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: No such file or directory (2).  

   WARN  Mon Jul 17 01:26:13 2023 (118): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: No such file or directory (2).  

   WARN  Mon Jul 17 01:26:13 2023 (119): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: No such file or directory (2).  

   WARN  Mon Jul 17 01:26:14 2023 (120): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: No such file or directory (2).  

   WARN  Mon Jul 17 01:26:14 2023 (121): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: No such file or directory (2).  

   WARN  Mon Jul 17 01:26:15 2023 (122): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: No such file or directory (2).  

   WARN  Mon Jul 17 01:26:15 2023 (123): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: No such file or directory (2).  

   WARN  Mon Jul 17 01:26:16 2023 (124): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: No such file or directory (2).  

   WARN  Mon Jul 17 01:26:16 2023 (125): Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: No such file or directory (2).
```

The error in centos 8 is '**Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad File Descriptor**'. Is there some permission issue? Or am I missing some file? How to solve this?

Comment: did you install or did you copy or downlod?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Bad file descriptor (9)' while running php artisan server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098717/fatal-error-unable-to-create-lock-file-bad-file-descriptor-9-while-running)

Comment: do you enable opcache ?

Comment: opcache is disabled. i downloaded the laravel project through some commands from chatgpt. i added /tmp folder in main /<root> with permission 1777. Now the error shows 'Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Read-only file system'.  composer install command installed the composer but gives warning in red: "PHP temp directory (/tmp) does not exist or is not writable to Composer. Set sys_temp_dir in your php.ini"

Answer (score 0):

check the permission of your project folder and if it's okay do composer install and check

Comment: i added /tmp folder in main /<root> with permission 1777. Now the error shows 'Fatal Error Unable to create lock file: Read-only file system'.

project permissions were proper with most of them as 0775. composer install command installed the composer but gives warning in red: "PHP temp directory (/tmp) does not exist or is not writable to Composer. Set sys_temp_dir in your php.ini"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426387/message-set-sys-temp-dir-in-your-php-ini-after-installed-composer Once go through this link